# Set formula for Computed column of PostgreSQL table in Entity Framework Core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a simple model with Id and a json property and a computed column which is value of **'tile'** key in the json column

```
public class Book 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="jsonb")]
    public string JsonInfo { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

in the configuration I set the way which the value of `Title` is caculated:

```
    builder.Property(t => t.Title).HasComputedColumnSql("(\"JsonInfo\"->>''title'')", stored:true).HasColumnType("varchar(150)");
```

the migration is build without problem, but unfortunately the database update ends with an error:

`42601: syntax error at or near "title"`

The problem is within the `"(\"JsonInfo\"->>''title'')"` that how the `title` is escaped. How can i fix it?

Just to mention, i use latest version of PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be escaping the title with twice single-quotes; the SQL you give to HasComputedColumnSql isn't a text literal, it's actual SQL. So the following should work:

```cs
.HasComputedColumnSql("\"JsonInfo\"->>'title'", stored: true)
```

Comment: Thanks @Shay-rojansky, but I actually solved the problem by specifying the column type: `("\"JsonInfo\"::jsonb->>'title'::text")`

Comment: You should not need that - try removing the `::jsonb` part. The thing that probably solves the problem is that you no longer have two single-quotes around `title`.